# Flutter List view insert

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list view data in which I want to display a custom banner after 5 list items and I tried the below method, but it is replacing that particular index item.

```
Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 50,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index % 5 == 0 && index != 0) {
                    return Banner();
                  }
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                  );
                }),
          )
```

It replacing the item index 5 and showing the banner so please help me how can I put the banner without losing any index data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work :

```dart
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 50,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index % 5 == 0 && index != 0)
      return Column(
        children: [
          Banner(),
          ListTile(title: Text('Index $index')),
        ],
      );
    else
      return ListTile(title: Text('Index $index'));
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {


            return Column(
              children :[
                  if (index % 5 == 0 && index != 0) 
                    Banner(),
                  
                ListTile(
                  title:Text("item $index")
                )
                ]
              
            );
             
          },
        ),
```

Comment: please provide some more info apart from the raw code to make it a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a minimal change from what you already have.

```
 return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 50,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index % 5 == 0 && index != 0)
          return Flex(
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              FlutterLogo(), //Banner()
              ListTile(title: Text('Index $index')),
            ],
          );
        else
          return ListTile(title: Text('Index $index'));
      },
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

I will show, how i did it, may be it will help.

```
class AddListItem{}

//List of your items
var originalList = [];

var listWithAdds = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < originalList.length; i++) {
      listWithAdds.add(value[i]);
      if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) {
        listWithAdds.add(AddListItem());
      }
    }

Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 50,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final item = listWithAdds[index];

                 if (item is AddListItem)
                 {
                    return Banner();
                 }

                 return ListTile(
                   title: Text('Item $index'),
                 );
                }),
          )
```